# Why javascript inline object creation an new add key does not work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a list of json objects `finallabelObjs` with key as `label` as follows:

```
var listoptionlabels = ["a", "b", "c"];
var finallabelObjs = [];
for(li in listoptionlabels) {finallabelObjs.push({}["label"] = listoptionlabels[li]);}


console.log(JSON.stringify(finallabelObjs));
```

I am getting output as `["a","b","c"]`. Is there no way I could achieve this in one line with minimal code. I don't want to create a temporary object literally inside the for loop and then pushing it to the `finallabelObjs` list.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/f3x1g9wn/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly push an object.

**Note:** Don't use `for..in` for array instead use `for..of`. And always use `let` or `const` in `for..in/of` loops.

```js
var listoptionlabels = ["a", "b", "c"];
var finallabelObjs = [];
for(let li of listoptionlabels) {finallabelObjs.push({"label":li})}
console.log(JSON.stringify(finallabelObjs));
```

Or a better way is to use `map()`

```js
var listoptionlabels = ["a", "b", "c"];
var finallabelObjs = listoptionlabels.map((label) => ({label}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(finallabelObjs));
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I was over thinking. Such simple solutions. But `map` is new to me. Is `map` synchronous? I mean does the control flow actually wait till iteration of all list elements is completed? I come from big data Spark world where map operations are kind of async.

Comment: @user3243499 Yes `map()` is synchronous.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra suggestions of not using for..in and use `let`. I am actually learning Javascript and very beginner.